# Segmentation fault when working with a 2d array of structures in c

Tags: c

I created a 2d array of structures and now I want to assign values to x, y, and z. Any ideas where the segmentation fault is coming from?

```
struct xyz
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

char buf[80];

struct xyz array[width][height];

for(row=1;row<=width;row++)
{
    for(col=1;col<=height;col++)
    { 
        fgets(buf,80,file);
        array[row][col].x = strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
        fgets(buf,80,file);
        array[row][col].y = strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
        fgets(buf,80,file);
        array[row][col].z = strtol(buf, NULL, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: array index goes from 0 to dim-1, not from 1 to dim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SI there a reason you're running from 1 to hight/col? In C all array begin in 0 and end in length-1.

In other word the for loops should look like:

```
for(row=0;row<width;row++)
{
   for(col=0;col<height;col++)
   {
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays start from `0` in C. You're stepping outside the allocated space since you're accessing `array[width]`. Perhaps you want:

```
for(row = 0; row < width; row++)
          ^      ^
```

Remember, if you declare `type array[LENGTH]`, it's never valid to touch the element `array[LENGTH]`. **The last valid element is `LENGTH - 1`**.

Comment: Okay I'm dumb. Thanks! Not sure why I thought 1 was a good idea for row and column, never used it before

Answer (score 3):

Your loops are going one out of bounds on the final iteration.

Your array size is `width` wide and `height` deep, so the first index is `[0][0]` and the maximum valid index is `[width - 1][height - 1]`. However, you use `<=` in your conditions, so you actually index `[width][height]` on the last iteration.

Also, arrays start from index `0`, not `1`, so start your loops from `0` instead of `1` and use `<`, not `<=`.